# Exception" 'System.InvalidOperationException' in PresentationCore.dll when adding multiple children to Grid/Border

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop

I'm having trouble with adding multiple children to a Grid in my WPF app. The issue is in CreateLayout() function on lines 74 and 93. Adding the first child to the childGrid and then adding the childGrid to the layoutGrid works fine. When trying to add a second child to childGrid i get the exception which is saying **'An infinite loop appears to have resulted from cross-dependent views'**. I do not use any Xaml code to show. CheckListBox inherits from UserControl

Here's my code:

```
using Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Scheduler;
using Syncfusion.Windows.Tools.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Media;


namespace MemoryFoam
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private StatusBar statusBar;
        private SchedulerCalendar? schedulerCalendar;
        private CheckListBox? checkListBox;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.MinWidth = 810;
            this.MinHeight = 670;
            this.Width = 810;
            this.Height = 670;


            statusBar = new StatusBar();
            var statusBarText = new TextBlock();
            statusBar.Items.Add(new StatusBarItem { Content = statusBarText });

            //SchedulerCalendar? schedulerCalendar = null;
            //CheckListBox? checkListBox = null;
            var SCInstanceAndGrid = CreateLayout(); //Item1 = SCInstance, Item2 = SCGrid
            SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
            {   //resize mainWindow
                this.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
                this.Height = e.NewSize.Height;
                //set statusBar's text
                statusBarText.Text = $"Zoom: {Width} x {Height}";
            };
            Grid.SetRow(statusBar, 1);
            Grid.SetColumn(statusBar, 0);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(statusBar, 2);
            
            var mainGrid = new Grid();
            mainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            mainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });

            mainGrid.Children.Add(statusBar);
            mainGrid.Children.Add(SCInstanceAndGrid.Item2);
            Content = mainGrid;
            
        }



        private (SchedulerCalendar, Grid) CreateLayout()
        {
            Grid layoutGrid = new Grid();
            schedulerCalendar = null;
            checkListBox = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Grid childGrid = new Grid();

                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:

                        childGrid.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                        schedulerCalendar = new SchedulerCalendar();
                        childGrid.Children.Add(schedulerCalendar);
                        childGrid.SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
                        {
                            if (schedulerCalendar.Height != e.NewSize.Height || schedulerCalendar.Width != e.NewSize.Width)
                            {
                                schedulerCalendar.Height = e.NewSize.Height;
                                schedulerCalendar.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
                            }
                        };

                        break;
                    case 1:

                        childGrid.Background = Brushes.Green;
                        break;
                    case 2:

                        childGrid.Background = Brushes.Blue;
                        checkListBox = new CheckListBox();
                        childGrid.Children.Add(checkListBox);
                        childGrid.SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
                        {
                            if (checkListBox.Height != e.NewSize.Height || checkListBox.Width != e.NewSize.Width)
                            {
                                checkListBox.Height = e.NewSize.Height;
                                checkListBox.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
                            }
                        };
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        childGrid.Background = Brushes.Orange;

                        break;
                }


             layoutGrid.Children.Add(childGrid);
             Grid.SetRow(childGrid, i / 2);
             Grid.SetColumn(childGrid, i % 2);

                
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
                row.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
                layoutGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);

                ColumnDefinition column = new ColumnDefinition();
                column.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
                layoutGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
            }

            return (schedulerCalendar, layoutGrid);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using Border instead of Grid and the issue was the same. I thought at first that the problem was that Border can have only one child but Grid can have multiple so it shouldn't present the same exception. I was wrong